# Syntax Error when trying to add "$" in front of numbers

Tags: bash, shell

Im trying to add a "$" in front of the numbers that are calculated below; the only successful one that was able to add the "$" was the Limit since it doesn't have any mathematical conflicts with the total, etc. How would I add the dollar sign in Cost, Tip, Total, Average. I tried to add it like i did with the limit but it gave me a syntax error. Please help me figure this out!

```
Percent=20
function calc {
  echo -n "What is the total cost in cents?";
  read cents
  guests=5
  Limit='$'$(awk "BEGIN{printf \"%.2f\n\", guests * 10  "); #added successfully
  Cost=$(echo "scale =2; $cents/100" | bc); #need to add $
  Percent=$(echo "scale =2; $Percent / 100" | bc);
  Tip=$(echo "scale =2; $Cost * $Percent" | bc); #need to add $
  Total=$(echo "scale =2; $Cost + $Tip" | bc); #need to add $
  Average=$(echo "scale =2; $Total/guests" | bc); #need to add $
}
```

I have a code similar posted but it isn't the same since the one before hand isn't helping me with the "$" issue that i'm having now

Comment: Do you see any problem with `Cost='$'$(echo "scale =2; $cents/100" | bc); #need to add $` ?

Comment: Yes this is what i get from my terminal 
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error

Comment: @socowi: No, this is not a duplicate of the question you pointed. OP is doing is in `bc`, not in `bash`

Comment: The "illegal character" looks like maybe copy/pasted string delimiters incorrectly, or something.  What is the *precise* command which caused this result?

Comment: `Cost='$'$(echo "scale =2; $cents/100" | bc); ` works on my system.

Comment: well what i did for Cost, Tip, Total and Average is similarly to Limit, I just added "$" in front of the $(echo // my code)

Comment: @anishane it shows the $, but it doesn't it gives me errors since Cost is being calculated in Tip, Total, Average, etc.

Comment: OK.. I think I understood your question. You want a `$` sign as a part of the variable value. But you want to bypass it in the subsequent usages of it in further calculations. e.g. `Cost` from the second step will become `$0.15` and when you use that later, `Tip=$(echo "scale =2; $Cost * $Percent" | bc)` will become `Tip=$(echo 'scale =2; $0.15* 20" | bc)`

Comment: Calculate all of them first and prefix them a `$` after all the calculations are done.

Comment: yes, and then it will be printed out along with the $value
So if cents is 2000

Then 
    Limit: $50.00
    Cost: $20.00
    Tip: $20 * 0.20 = $4.00
    Total: $20.00+$4.00= $24.00 
    Average $24.00/5 = $4.80

Comment: How would i do that? @anishsane

Comment: First, calculate all of them without any printing decoration like `$`. Then finally, during printing, you can print it with something like `echo "Total Cost = \$$Cost"`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add the `$` to variables while you still use the variables to calculate something. Its working for `Limit` because `Limit` isn't used in the following calculations. Execute the program "by hand" and see what happens:

What happens:

```
Cost='$12.00' # value computed by hand
Tip='$1.00'   # value computed by hand
Total=$(echo 'scale=2; $12.00 + $1.00' | bc); # filled in values of variables
```

`bc` doesn't know how to handle the `$`. Complete all calculations without the `$` and then (at the very end) add the `$`.

```
# ongoing calculations
Cost='$'"$Cost"
Tip='$'"$Tip"
Total='$'"$Total"
Average='$'"$Average"
```

Answer (score 1):

The trivial answer is that you can paste together strings by quoting or escaping the parts which need to be protected from the shell, which in this case is the `$` character which otherwise is a shell metacharacter.

```
Average=\$$(echo "scale =2; $Total/guests" | bc)  # or
Average='$'$(echo "scale =2; $Total/guests" | bc) # or
Average="$"$(echo "scale =2; $Total/guests" | bc)
```

Your actual problem seems to be that you are using `guests` in Awk as if it were an Awk variable, but Awk doesn't know that the shell has a variable with this name.

More fundamentally, running a large amount of `echo` commands in subshells is an antipattern.  You are already using Awk -- refactor it so it produces all the results you need in one go.  Perhaps like this:

```
Percent=20
calc () {   # notice also the switch to POSIX function definition syntax
  read -p "What is the total cost in cents?" cents
  # Can't use shell variable in Awk script!
  set -- $(awk -v guests=5 -v cents="$cents" -v percent="$Percent" '
    BEGIN{cost=cents/100; tip=cost*percent; total=cost+tip; average=total/guests;
        printf "%.2f $%.2f %.2f $%.2f $%.2f $%.2f\n", guests * 10,
            cost, percent/100, tip, total, average}')
  Limit=$1
  Cost=$2
  Percent=$3
  Tip=$4
  Total=$5
  Average=$6
}
```

The function of `set -- some tokens` is to set `$1` to `some`, `$2` to `tokens`, etc, i.e. a quick and succinct (but arguably obscure) way to set the command-line arguments to a set of values of your choosing.

You'll notice that I factored in the dollar signs into the `printf` format string.

Even more fundamentally, having a function create a large number of variables to be used elsewhere in your shell script is also a vague yet distinct bad smell.  Are you sure this script really wants to be a shell script?  Are you really sure this particular design is maintainable?

Comment: A related design is to have Awk output a snippet of shell script and passing that to `eval` but we like to avoid `eval` because it has the potential of creating a significant security hole if used incorrectly.